# Regular languages closed under quotients with arbitrary languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

When proving that that the quotient of a regular language $R$ and an arbitrary language $B$, I understand you take a DFA $M$ accepting $R$, and then construct a DFA that is the same, but its final states are those from which we can reach a final state of $M$ with a string from $B$. How can we just say it's possible to take such a set?

Does this proof also work for a similar property (I don't know the name) that creates the set
$\{ x \mid \forall y \in B : xy \in R \} $?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried proving or disproving it?

Comment: It's the question of constructing such sets of states from which we reach a final state by some/all strings of B. Would we need to prove they are decidable?

Comment: No, there is no requirement of computability here.

Answer (score 4):

The *(right) quotient* of $R$ by $B$ is the language
$$
  RB^{-1} = \{x \in A^* \mid \exists y \in B,\ xy \in R\}
$$
and indeed, if $(Q, A, \cdot, q_0, F)$ is the minimal DFA of $R$, then $RB^{-1}$ is accepted by the automaton $(Q, A, \cdot, q_0, S)$, where 
$$
S = \{q \in Q \mid \exists y \in B\ \ q \cdot y  \in F\}.
$$
On the other hand, let $R/B =  \{x \in A^* \mid \forall y \in B\ \ xy \in R\}$. Then one gets
$$
  R/B = \bigcap_{y \in B} \{ x \in A^* \mid xy \in R \} = \bigcap_{y \in B} Ry^{-1}
$$
Since $R$ is regular, there are only finitely many distinct languages of the form $Ry^{-1}$, and each of it is regular. It follows that $R/B$ is also regular.

This gives a proof that the languages $RB^{-1}$ and $R/B$ are regular for any $B$. However, if you want to find **effectively** an automaton accepting these languages, this is a different story and you may need to identify which of the right quotients  $Ru^{-1}$ are of the form $Ry^{-1}$ with $y \in B$, a question that might be undecidable, depending on $B$ and $R$...